# I am getting an error in libGDX program only for the Android Build

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I successfully imported a libGDX Gradle build in Eclipse Mars. Then, I see a red cross on the Android Build. When I open the Android.java file, it gives a bunch of errors on different things.

The errors look like this:

The type android.os.Handler cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files for package com.arch.project.android;

The import android.os.Bundle cannot be resolved for import android.os.Bundle

The hierarchy of the type AndroidLauncher is inconsistent for public class Android Launcher

The type android.app.Activity cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files for public class Android Launcher extends AndroidApplication.

Bundle cannot be resolved to a type for `protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {`

See the picture for more details!
[Screenshot of android build of libgdx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijnuk.png)

Comment: did you import the jar files of the libgdx situated in the libs folder ?

Comment: and did you install the android sdk?

Comment: I have installed the Android SDK and I don't really know which .jar files to include as I am new to libGDX. Thanks for responding!

Comment: If you set everything up correctly, you don't have to import anything manually. Note that you need a specific version of the sdk files (check the libgdx page) (your screenshot displays exactly what happens if you do NOT have the correct ones, or any at all). Did you use the setup GUI tool? Did you create the gradle build with the setup GUI tool?

Comment: Yes I used the libgdx setup tool. Its like a black window with white and red text.

Comment: I just found out the method to make this work! Thanks for responding! So for people having the same error, you just have to install the adt plugin for eclipse. Then restart eclipse, and you will have no errors!

Comment: This is what I meant with the SDK, of course you need to add it to eclipse. So for all the others, go to https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-%28Eclipse%2C-Intellij-IDEA%2C-NetBeans%29 and follow the setps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found a way to remove the errors because I just did what it says in the website. I installed the adt plugin for eclipse and the errors were gone. Thanks again for the concern! :)